# Php connection to Sphinx refused

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

I have installed Sphinx on my server and everything seems to working, except that when I run the test.php from web browser, I am getting this error:
Query failed: connection to localhost:9312 failed (errno=111, msg=Connection refused).

I have searched online, including stack overflow, almost all suggestions were make sure the searchd service is running, and it's listening on the right port. I can say yes to both questions because if run the same test program directly in command line, everything works. I understand that the hosting provider may not have opened the port, but the port should be listening with the server, right? The fact that it works under command line should confirm that the service is listening on that port and the php program is able to get through to it. So I don't understand why the same program run from the web browser rejects the connection.

I have also enabled fsockopen in php.ini.

Any suggestion to help understand why the connection is rejected or even better how to solve it is very welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Is the server you acessing on the 'command line' the same one as runs the webserver? Maybe you are connecting to a different server?

Comment: I am facing same problem, and my database is in same server. Please suggest any me what should I do now.

Comment: What happens if you try, `curl localhost:9312` from the server?

Comment: Check your searchd.log. Also check the config file to make sure you do not have any path errors and that the port is set properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

- check your sphinx.conf and make sure that 9312 is your spinx's port (my default port was 3312)
- change localhost to 127.0.0.1

If this doesn't work for you check if port is open, you can do it with nmap

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
nmap 127.0.0.1 -p 9312
```